# Force disable directive cache or reload angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How do I force re-render my directive

Template

```
<div ng-if="showDirective">
  <my-directive attr="value"></my-directive>
</div>
<button ng-click="toggleDirective()">Toggle</button>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.showDirective = true 

  $scope.toggleDirective = function() {
    $scope.showDirective = !$scope.showDirective;
  }
```

I have an ajax request in the directive which fetches the data and loop though ng-repeat.

Directive load for the first time on page load. When I click on the toggle button first time it hides the directive, when I click on the toggle again loads from the cache or renders the previous dom. How do I force re-render the directive when ever its show..

Answer (score 0):

Re-compile markup is the only chance to re-render it....

HOWEVER, why would you do that? Maybe it would be enough to just update your list in ng-repeat? AngularJS will see changes and re-render the list itself, no need for manual rer-endering.

Comment: My use case is bit complex, The directive is a child directive which will be inside a parent directive, its recursive!! I need to update the child directive when the immediate parent directive is changed.. Then the tricky part is both have isolated scopes..

Comment: Then recompile it. It's expensive and might not be the best solution, but might work for you. I wouldn't recommend it though.. I'm sure you could figure out some solution for it to work.. Recompiling is a dirty trick in this case.